# Automatically installing dependencies on deploy within Fuse

Tags: java, fuseesb

I've running a JBoss Fuse 6.0 server. When I deploy my application, I get the following error:

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
>   TestWebService [252]: Unable to resolve 252.0: missing requirement
>   [252.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.jdbc.core)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))

I believe this error is happening because the container does not have the bundle installed. Is there a way for me to tell it to download and install any bundles it does not have on deploy from our artifactory?

Answer (score 1):

In your fuse etc directory, locate the file org.apache.karaf.features.cfg.  On the line for features repositories add:

```
mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/standard/2.3.0.redhat-60024/xml/features,
mvn:org.apache.karaf.assemblies.features/enterprise/2.3.0.redhat-60024/xml/features
```

and on the line for features boot, add:

```
spring, 
spring-jdbc
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, so that added spring-jdbc - however, now it's complaining about spring-beans. I'm assuming I'll need to load that and all the sub-dependencies as well? I'm new to Fuse so this feel like a big step back from just packing this webservice as a war and deploying to Weblogic, for example. I must be missing something simple?

Comment: Are you sure you included "spring" in your featuresBoot?  I just tested it with Jboss Fuse 6.0, with the set up I described and it loaded Spring Beans, Spring Context Support, Spring Context, Spring AOP etc...  The spring feature packs all those, then the spring-jdbc feature is something a little extra.

Comment: You can type "exports | grep org.springframework.beans" to see if any bundles are actually exporting spring-beans.

Comment: I did include that and I now see Spring JDBC 3.1.2 in the Karaf web console. However, when I deploy, I still get the same issue - ignore my earlier comment about it working :/

Comment: I believe the reason it's failing is because the bundle did not actually activate for the following reason: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.jdbc [254]: Unable to resolve 254.0: missing requirement [254.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=3.1.2)(!(version>=3.1.3))). 

So this means that I need to install a previous version of spring beans than it downloaded automatically?

Comment: Yes so one thing to know if that fuse docent necessarily look for a specific version, but a range of versions.  The error message basically says it wants a version between 3.1.2 and 3.1.3.  What is strange though is that you are including spring from a pre complied features file, which is guaranteed to include comparable versions.  In your Manifest file, have you supplied the version you are using manually? Or are you allowing fuse to resolve the versions?  Also would it be possible to see the full error log (under ${fuse_home}/data/log)?